# How to query language name string from given LANGID properly?

Tags: windows, winapi, locale, nls

**On input** I have a language ID.
**On output** I do expect *full localized name of the language*.

I use `GetLocaleInfo(..., LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, ... )` to populate the string. Everyting worked fine until I received `0` on input and `GetLocaleInfo` filled the string with user default language instead of indicating neutral language (expected).
To my knowledge, no special LOCALE_XXX_DEFAULT constants equals to `0`.

Here is a testcase:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  wIDLanguage: WORD;
  lpLCData: string;
  cchData: Integer;
begin
  wIDLanguage := 0;
  Assert(wIDLanguage = MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL));

  cchData := GetLocaleInfo(MAKELCID(wIDLanguage, SORT_DEFAULT), LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, nil, 0);
  Win32Check(cchData <> 0);
  //Win32Check(GetLastError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
  SetLength(lpLCData, cchData);
  Win32Check(GetLocaleInfo(MAKELCID(wIDLanguage, SORT_DEFAULT), LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, PChar(lpLCData), Length(lpLCData)) <> 0);
  SetLength(lpLCData, Length(lpLCData) - 1);

  Caption := '"' + lpLCData + '"';
end;
```

- **What am I doing wrong here?**
- **How to retrieve language name properly?**